# Using Javascript to combine two <a> tags into one

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have something like this:

```
<a href="#"> &plusmn;</a>
<a href="#"> Link Here</a>
```

I want it to look like:

```
<a href="#"> &plusmn; Link Here</a>
```

However, due to limitations within WordPress I'm a little unsure how to combine them JavaScript wise.

Comment: Needs clarification, unless this is literally all you want to do with this exact markup.

Comment: Limitations withing `wordpress`? How are those two anchors created ?

Comment: If you explain how you are getting to different links instead of one may be you get better answer instead of combining them after

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
a1.textContent += a2.textContent;
a2.parentNode.removeChild(a2);
```

where `a1` and `a2` are the references to those two ANCHOR elements. (Once you get the reference to the first anchor, you can get the reference to the second one like so: `a1.nextElementSibling`.)

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/QWQy8/

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** See @Šime Vidas' comment for a slimmer method.

---

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CASff/)**

**jQuery:**

```
$('a + a').prev().html(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + $(this).next().html());
    $(this).next().remove();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#"> &plusmn;</a>
<a href="#"> Link Here</a>

<a href="#"> &plusmn;</a>
<a href="#"> Another Link Here</a>
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="#"> ± Link Here</a>

<a href="#"> ± Another Link Here</a>
```

Comment: You can slim those two lines into this: `$(this).append($(this).next().remove().html());` - [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/CASff/1/)

Comment: @Šime: Thank you. I'm fairly new to jQuery so I don't know all the shortcuts just yet. :)